# Emit websocket event from a NestJS controller or service

Tags: websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I am trying to listen to model change events in TypeORM through a subscriber, and broadcast an event each time a new one is inserted. While external clients receive the event, the gateway's `@SubscribeMessage()` method is not receiving it, which suggests that the sender is not getting the event. However, according to [socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/), the `of('namespace').emit('event')` should be received to any client, including the sender.

The gateway is injected to the subscriber service without any issue, and the gateway's server seems to be ready when I try to use it, but no event is emitted.

Running on NestJS 6.3.1, I have also tried emitting the event from the controller, with no results.

```js
@WebSocketGateway({ namespace: '/posts' })
export class PostGateway {

  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Namespace;

  @SubscribeMessage('create')
  handleMessage(client: Socket, payload: Post): void {
    console.log('handling', payload);
  }

}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class PostSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<Post> {

  private socket: Namespace;

  constructor(
    @InjectConnection() readonly connection: Connection,
    private readonly gateway: PostGateway,
  ) {
    connection.subscribers.push(this);
    this.socket = gateway.server;
  }

  listenTo() {
    return Measurement;
  }

  afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<Post>): void {
    this.gateway.server.emit('create', event.entity);
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure about what the problem is with you code. What I find helpful to use with websockets though, is the network tab in chrome that you can get to by inspecting the page. If you select the network tab and then select WS as the communication type it should show you all the incoming and outgoing messages. Hope this helps.

Comment: I ended up injecting the service and using an RxJS Subject to receive such events.

Comment: Since this is communication between services, it cannot be easily inspected, but socket.io provides debug strings for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about what it the problem in your code. But I can give some few things to check.
these are some suggestions:

1. Make sure that the PostGateway is connected and its server is
   initialized properly.
2. Check the Namespace Connection

   `if (!this.socket) { console.error('Socket is not initialized!'); }`
3. Check Gateway Initialization in the Main Module
4. Debugging Emitting Events
5. Check the client is correctly connecting to the specified namespace (/posts) and subscribing to the 'create' event.

   socket.on('create', (data) => {
   console.log('Received create event:', data);
   });